# limit of a distribution

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

> Show that $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}  \left\langle \frac{\epsilon}{x^{2}+ \epsilon} ,\phi \right\rangle =\langle \delta,\phi\rangle $$
>   where $\phi\in D(\mathbb{R}) $ and $ \frac{\epsilon}{x^{2}+ \epsilon} \in D' (\mathbb{R}) $

What I tried is this:
$ \frac{\epsilon}{x^{2}+ \epsilon}$ is an integrable function hence 
$\left\langle \frac{\epsilon}{x^{2}+ \epsilon} ,\phi\right\rangle$ defines an integral on $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\left\langle\frac{\epsilon}{x^{2}+ \epsilon} ,\phi\right\rangle = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon}{x^{2}+ \epsilon} \phi (x) dx$$

How can I take limit of the last equation?

Thank you from now on.

Comment: did you try partial integration and splitting up the integral at 0?

Comment: Wasn't it $\frac{\epsilon}{x^2 + \epsilon^2}$? And there's a constant factor ($\frac{1}{\pi}$) missing then.

Comment: @DanielFischer no. It is how I wrote it in the question.

Comment: In that case, substituting $x = \sqrt{\epsilon}\, y$ will show the limit is $0$, not $\delta$.

Comment: To prove what Daniel Fischer suggested, you can integrate by parts to see that you have $-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) \arctan(x/\epsilon) dx$. Now split this integral between $(-\infty,-\sqrt{\epsilon}),(-\sqrt{\epsilon},\sqrt{\epsilon})$ and $(\sqrt{\epsilon},\infty)$. The middle interval is small and everything is bounded so it is not important. What happens on the other two intervals? (Hint: how does $\arctan$ behave at large arguments?)

Comment: @Ian Is it $ arctan(x\ \sqrt \epsilon)$ in that integral?

Comment: @SerkanYaray No, I had it right.

Comment: @Ian No need to integrate by parts: $\frac {\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon}\le 1[x^2\le \sqrt \epsilon]+\sqrt \epsilon[x^2> \sqrt \epsilon]$.

Comment: @A.S. I meant the first thing Daniel Fischer suggested (with the $\epsilon^2$ in the problem).

Comment: I am sorry,why do you need $ \epsilon ^{2} $ I really didn't understand why you are changing the problem?

Comment: With the $\epsilon$, your problem statement is wrong, in that the family of distributions in question converges to $0$, not $\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some people pointed to you you should consider the delta sequence
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{n}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2}$$
Which gives

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} <f_n(x), \phi(x) > =<\delta(x), \phi(x) >$$

**Note:** you can put $\epsilon =\frac{1}{n}$ and consider the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to 0.