# Lorentzian Delta Function Sifting Property

Tags: dirac-delta

Using the Lorentzian as the delta function

$$\delta(x) ~=~ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2+x^2}$$

Is there a way to rigorously prove the sifting property, namely

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x) \delta(x-t) dx  = f(t)$$

Comment: I don't quite follow. With your definitions, clearly the integral is always zero.

Comment: It should be $\epsilon $ in the numerator not $\epsilon^2$? See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639482/limit-of-a-distribution/1639604#1639604).